# Holoeverywhere tabs load the first one when I slide over the last tab?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-holo-everywhere, actionbarsherlock-map

Recently, I am using holoeverywhere to do something, but now I am facing a problem that when I keep sliding to right after reaching the last tab, the program will load the first tab's view but there is no more tabs, so the program will crash. The problem is described following and I really need someone to help me.
Thanks to you all!

The following is my Code:

```
public static class TabFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(getSupportActivity());
        textView.setText("Position: " + getArguments().getInt("position"));
        return textView;
    }
}

 private static Bundle make(int i) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("position", i);
        return bundle;
    }

@Override
protected void onHandleTabs() {
    getSupportActionBar().removeAllTabs();
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        addTab("Tab #" + i, TabFragment.class, make(i + 1));
}
```

The problem is that when I slide after the last tab, the view will like this:

[image]

and the program will crash with the following error:

```
05-05 21:33:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1573): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-05 21:33:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1573): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 5, size is 5
05-05 21:33:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1573):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
05-05 21:33:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1573):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
05-05 21:33:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1573):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.getTabAt(ActionBarImpl.java:989)
05-05 21:33:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1573):     at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.app.ActionBarWrapper.getTabAt(ActionBarWrapper.java:425)
05-05 21:33:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1573):     at org.holoeverywhere.app.TabSwipeActivity.dispatchTabSelected(TabSwipeActivity.java:135)
05-05 21:33:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1573):     at org.holoeverywhere.app.TabSwipeActivity.access$2(TabSwipeActivity.java:128)
05-05 21:33:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1573):     at org.holoeverywhere.app.TabSwipeActivity$TabSwipeAdapter.onPageSelected(TabSwipeActivity.java:67)
05-05 21:33:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1573):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.scrollToItem(ViewPager.java:538)
05-05 21:33:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1573):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:523)
05-05 21:33:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1573):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:1943)
05-05 21:33:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1573):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:5486)
05-05 21:33:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1573):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1953)
05-05 21:33:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1573):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1714)
05-05 21:33:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1573):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
05-05 21:33:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1573):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1728)
05-05 21:33:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1573):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
05-05 21:33:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1573):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1728)
05-05 21:33:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1573):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
05-05 21:33:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1573):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1728)
05-05 21:33:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1573):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
05-05 21:33:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1573):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1728)
05-05 21:33:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1573):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
05-05 21:33:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1573):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1728)
05-05 21:33:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1573):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1892)
05-05 21:33:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1573):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1371)
05-05 21:33:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1573):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2364)
05-05 21:33:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1573):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1840)
05-05 21:33:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1573):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:5662)
05-05 21:33:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1573):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:2863)
05-05 21:33:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1573):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
05-05 21:33:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1573):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-05 21:33:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1573):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-05 21:33:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1573):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
05-05 21:33:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1573):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-05 21:33:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1573):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-05 21:33:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1573):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-05 21:33:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1573):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-05 21:33:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1573):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and I also used some customized settings:

```
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.****,null));
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
View homeIcon = findViewById(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ? android.R.id.home : R.id.abs__home);
((View) homeIcon.getParent()).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

and this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

The following is the demo's code and I just do not understand. In the demo, when I side to right after reaching the last tab, the program will show something at the right side of the screen like this:

[image]

and these are the demo's code:

```
public static class TabFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("DemoTabsActivity", "test" + getArguments().getInt("position"));
        TextView textView = new TextView(getSupportActivity());
        textView.setText("Position: " + getArguments().getInt("position"));
        return textView;
    }
}

private static Bundle make(int i) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("position", i);
    return bundle;
}

@Override
protected void onHandleTabs() {
    getSupportActionBar().removeAllTabs();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        addTab("Tab #" + i, TabFragment.class, make(i + 1));
    Log.d("TAG", "getSupportActionBar().getTabCount()" + getSupportActionBar().getTabCount());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 5, size is 5
```

Somewhere in your code you're trying to access/modify the fifth element of an array that has only four elements.

Comment: I updated the demo's code above and I can hardly find the difference.

Comment: The error and the problem remain the same so at least you will know where to look for errors now

Comment: It seem that it is not that easy

Comment: What is on this line `ActionBarImpl.java:989` ?